# Uber in Germany (esp. Cologne and Frankfurt)

Tags: germany, taxis, uber

Is there Uber service in Germany?

I am particularly interested in Cologne and Frankfurt, but to make the question more useful to others as well, a general answer in Germany would be welcomed.  Typing "uber in cologne" in Google gave contradictory results.

If there is Uber in Germany, do you recommend using it?

Comment: Questions like this are going to vary strongly over time (due to actions by company, regulatory, injunctions etc.), so it's better to state it as "Which German cities is Uber in, as of mid-2023?". And distrust third-party data on Google/Google Maps as it can be stale scraped stuff that can be up to 7 years old, IME.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Uber [is available in Cologne](https://www.uber.com/global/de/cities/cologne/?uclick_id=2a0a1d36-6103-42ed-9bcc-99331eeac454). Those answers provided by google should always be taken with a hefty pinch of salt - if you click through you'll see that the source for the quote in your first screenshot is a post on a trip advisor forum from "5 years ago" (exact date not displayed) and the quote in the second screenshot is from an article written in October 2018.

As for where Uber is available in Germany more generally, their website has [a list of cities where they operate](https://www.uber.com/global/de/cities/?uclick_id=2a0a1d36-6103-42ed-9bcc-99331eeac454). Currently in Germany that is:

Berlin
Cologne
Düsseldorf
Frankfurt
Hamburg
Hannover
Mannheim
Munich
Rostock
Stuttgart

Note that Uber's model where essentially anybody with a suitable vehicle can sign up as a driver is not legal in Germany. In Germany it's essentially just a platform where you can reserve normal taxis operated by licensed taxi companies. They still have Uber's demand-based variable pricing model rather than the usual rates (set by local authorities) which apply if you catch a cab yourself.

Whether Uber can be recommended is probably a bit opinion-heavy for this site, but for me: I don't see any particular benefit. They're basically normal taxis except the pricing is less predictable. But if you don't speak German, I can imagine the app might make things easier.

Comment: Even in UK Uber has begun "farming out" its bookings to the more traditional private hire operators, who use drivers with local knowledge and experience, whereas the Uber business model exploits loopholes in the incredibly outdated legislation: the Town Police Clauses Act 1847, and widely varying local authority bye-laws, which cannot control vehicles and drivers licensed by them but operating outside their area. And none of them seem to have caught up with the 'electronic hail' which allows a private hire to operate like a hackney.

Comment: Isn't the main benefit that you can summon a taxi by pressing a button vs trying to figure out which number to call for a local company?

Comment: To note: there are plenty of other taxi apps which allow you to hail a regular taxi, sometimes local and sometimes cross country. Uber has no special place in Germany.

Comment: In Cologne and Frankfurt, I would expect that the majority of taxi drivers and certainly the majority of people manning the phones in the taxi office speak English well enough for you to book a taxi and tell them where to go.

Comment: *But if you don't speak German, I can imagine the app might make things easier.* I fond this to be THE most important thing abroad in a country I do not speak the language and the ones I speak may not be that prevalent. The app is the same everywhere and you do not need to exchange a word - and yet get to the expected place.